# How to provide different styling for individual words in a TextInput in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to format individual words that a user types in a TextInput field, while they are typing it. How may I go about doing this?

For example, say a user types the following in the TextInput element: "Hello there. I am looking for help". So what I want is, that all words here be black, except for the word "looking", which has to be red in colour. And I want "looking" to change from black to red as soon as the user has done typing the work "looking" in the TextInput field.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add an example or clarify your question?

Comment: Yes. For example, say a user types the following in the TextInput element: "Hello there. I am looking for help". So what I want is, that all words here be black, except for the word "looking", which has to be red in colour. And I want "looking" to change from black to red as soon as the user has done typing the work "looking" in the TextInput field. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Nothing towards this. Because I don't know how to go about having a different style for individual words in TextInput element. One idea that I had is to overlay a <Text> element on top of the <TextInput> element which would display what the user is typing (in a way that it looks like its being typed in the TextInput element itself). Doing this, would enable me to format each individual word however I want... But this is a little messy.. Is there any easier way out?